# jquery ui autocomplete custom renderitem how to assign value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How do I assign values to elements generated by autocomplete. I Attempts to do so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {\
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("\<li\>"),
        wrapper = $("\<div\>", {
          text: item.label
        });
      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }
      if (item.value == 1) {
        $("\<img src=".. / img / web.png " /\>", {}).appendTo(wrapper);
      }
      $("\<span style='display:none' \>" + item.value + "\</span\>", {}).appendTo(li);
      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    }
  });
  $("#people").iconselectmenu().iconselectmenu("menuWidget").addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");
});

$('#people').on('change', function() {
  $('.uiselectmenutext').html("111");
}).change();
```

Is there any other way?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review the following for assistance first: https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render If ou need more assistance, please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm simulating a select menu through it but I need a default option how can I set the default option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following example built on the jQuery UI [Selectmenu Demo](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#custom_render).

```js
$(function() {
  $.widget("custom.iconselectmenu", $.ui.selectmenu, {
    _renderItem: function(ul, item) {
      var li = $("<li>"),
        wrapper = $("<div>").html(item.label);
      if (item.disabled) {
        li.addClass("ui-state-disabled");
      }
      if (item.value == 1) {
        $("<img>", {
          src: "../img/web.png"
        }).appendTo(wrapper);
      }
      $("<span>").css("display", "none").html(item.value).appendTo(li);
      return li.append(wrapper).appendTo(ul);
    }
  });

  $("#people").iconselectmenu().iconselectmenu("menuWidget").addClass("ui-menu-icons avatar");

  $('#people').on('change', function() {
    $('.uiselectmenutext').html("111");
  }).change();
});
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
}


/* select with custom icons */

.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 3em;
}

.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-menu.customicons .ui-menu-item .ui-icon {
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  top: 0.1em;
}

.ui-icon.video {
  background: url("images/24-video-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.ui-icon.podcast {
  background: url("images/24-podcast-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}

.ui-icon.rss {
  background: url("images/24-rss-square.png") 0 0 no-repeat;
}


/* select with CSS avatar icons */

option.avatar {
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.avatar .ui-icon {
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="demo">
  <form action="#">
    <h2>Selectmenu with framework icons</h2>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="people">Select a File:</label>
      <select name="filesA" id="people">
        <option value="1" data-class="ui-icon-script">jQuery.js</option>
        <option value="2" data-class="ui-icon-image">jQuery Logo</option>
        <option value="3" data-class="ui-icon-script">ui.jQuery.js</option>
        <option value="4" selected="selected" data-class="ui-icon-image">jQuery UI Logo</option>
        <option value="5" disabled="disabled" data-class="ui-icon-help">Some unknown file</option>
      </select>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

It is not clear why you had additional slashes in your code. These should not be needed when creating new Objects. Additionally, you will want to call the Custom Widget from outside the definition of the widget.